# How do I designate a specific file for my patching script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am making a batch script that will locate a text file, then replace a specified string within the file. The only problem I'm having is setting the path of the specified file. I've tried using `cd` to set the path but it seems to do nothing. Will using `cd` work or do I need to use different or additional parameters? Here is my current script:

```
@echo off
SET TARGETPATH= "%TARGETPATH%"

setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

cd "%TARGETPATH%"
set search=Hello
set replace=Goodbye
set textFile=Test.txt

:PowerShell
SET PSScript=%temp%\~tmpStrRplc.ps1
ECHO (Get-Content "%~dp0%textFile%").replace("%search%", "%replace%") ^| Set-Content "%~dp0%textFile%">"%PSScript%"

SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%'"
EXIT

:END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Targetpath hasn't any effect and is superfluous.
2. Powershell should already be reachable via a path entry.
3. The ps-script could be wrapped in a simple command, no need for a temp file.

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\04\14\SU_1313967.cmd
@echo off
Setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set search=Hello
set replace=Goodbye
set "textFile=%~dp0Test.txt"

Powershell -NonI -NoP -C "(GC \"%textFile%\").replace(\"%search%\", \"%replace%\") | SC \"%textFile%\""
```

Comment: I can see how this also replaces text, but how do I point this script to a specific file to be patched?

Comment: Pass via cmd line parameter (`%1`) or user input `set /p "textfile=Enter the file to modify"`